# how to use conditional trigger in sql server for update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

```
---------------table1--------------------------------------------
    id    |   name  | lname   |   displayStatus   | delStatus
    1         a         b               1              0
    2         aa        bb              0              0
    3         aaa       bbb             1              0
    4         aaaa      bbbb            0              1

---------------tbl_LOG--------------------------------------------
    id    |   rowData| actType
```

and i have this trigger for update:

```
alter trigger tgr_delete
on table1
after update
as
begin
    declare @rowData nvarchar(max), @username nvarchar(50)

    if update(delStatus)
    begin
        if((select delStatus from inserted) = 1)
        begin
            set @rowData = (select CAST((CAST(id as nvarchar(12)) + ' | ' + name) as nvarchar(max)) from inserted)

            exec sp_insert_LOG 'table1', @rowData, 2
        end
        else if((select delStatus from inserted) = 0)
        begin
            set @rowData = (select CAST((CAST(id as nvarchar(12)) + ' | ' + name) as nvarchar(max)) from inserted)

            exec sp_insert_LOG 'table1', @rowData, 3
        end
    end
    else if update(displayStatus)
    begin
        if((delStatus = 0 or delStatus is null) and (select displayStatus from inserted) = 0)
        begin
            set @rowData = (select CAST((CAST(id as nvarchar(12)) + ' | ' + name) as nvarchar(max)) from inserted)

            exec sp_insert_LOG 'table1', @rowData, 4
        end
        else if((delStatus = 0 or delStatus is null) and (select displayStatus from inserted) = 1)
        begin
            set @rowData = (select CAST((CAST(id as nvarchar(12)) + ' | ' + name) as nvarchar(max)) from inserted)

            exec sp_insert_LOG 'table1', @rowData, 5
        end
    end
end
```

and i have 3 stored procedure

- first is for update delStatus
- second is for update displayStatus
- and third is for update all column

now What should I do to avoid interfering with the first two conditions.

Comment: Just checking if I understand the question - You want the trigger to work only if either `delStatus` or `displayStatus` is changed, but not if they are changed together or if any other column is also changed?

Comment: yes. i want this.

Comment: Triggers in sql works per statement, not per row. If you ever run a multi-row update statement on your table1 it will fail. checking what columns have changed can be done by comparing the values between deleted and inserted using an inner join on the primary key (assuming id in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer since I don't know what `sp_insert_LOG` does, but it should get you started on the right direction:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Table1_Update ON Table1
FOR UPDATE
AS


DECLARE @LogData AS TABLE
(
    TableName sysname,
    RowData nvarchar(max),
    ActionType int
)

INSERT INTO @LogData (TableName, RowData, ActionType)
SELECT 'Table1', 
       CAST((CAST(id as nvarchar(12)) + ' | ' + name) as nvarchar(max)),
       CASE WHEN i.delStatus = 1 THEN 2
            WHEN i.delStatus = 0 THEN 3
            WHEN ISNULL(i.delStatus, 0) = 0 AND i.displayStatus = 0 THEN 4
            WHEN ISNULL(i.delStatus, 0) = 0 AND i.displayStatus = 1 THEN 5
       END
FROM INSERTED i 
INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.Id = d.Id
WHERE (i.name = d.name OR i.name IS NULL and d.name IS NULL)
AND (i.lname = d.lname OR i.lname IS NULL and d.lname IS NULL)
AND
(
(
    ISNULL(i.delStatus, 0) <> ISNULL(d.delStatus, 0)
    AND ISNULL(i.displayStatus, 0) = ISNULL(d.displayStatus, 0)
)
OR 
(
    ISNULL(i.delStatus, 0) = ISNULL(d.delStatus, 0)
    AND ISNULL(i.displayStatus, 0) <> ISNULL(d.displayStatus, 0)
)
)
```

At this point, the `@LogData` table contains whatever data you would send to `sp_insert_LOG`. I suggest to create a new stored procedure like `sp_insert_log` that will accept a table valued parameter and handle this data.